# About multiple background images with the same value in 'background-image' property;

Tags: css, background-image, linear-gradients

```css
.div{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            border-top:20px solid black;
            border-bottom:20px solid black;
            background-position: 0%,100%;
            -webkit-background-size: 20px 100%;
            -moz-background-size: 20px 100%;
            background-size: 20px 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, green), linear-gradient(to bottom, red, green);
        }
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
```

When I using multiple backgrounds,why set the the same value in background-image property,but the first background image is not covered by the second image.I am so confused,anyone know?Thanks in advance；

ok，sorry，nobody can understand the question,maybe because my description is too bad.
my mean is I set two values for 'background-image' property with linear-gradient to set two background images,look this:

```
background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, red, yellow),linear-gradient(to bottom, red, yellow);
```

And set other background property the same,look this:

```
background-position:0%,100%;
background-size:20px 100%;
```

Ok,the two background images all the properties are same ,so the first background image should cover by the second image,but not,they are shown on the left and right,why?

Comment: Hello Anan, your question is very hard to understand. Please consider using full, grammatically correct sentences for the problem statement.

Comment: We can't understand your query first Improve your question If possible could you share screenshot or rough sketch for what exact you are looking for ? So that we can help you.

Comment: Just googled what I think is your issue: you should look at [this link about multiple backgrounds](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This style

```
background-size:20px 100%;
```

Mean that the horizontal size of the background is 20px. Since there is only one value, it applies to both gradients.

This other style

```
background-position:0%,100%;
```

Has 2 values, so the first applies to the first gradient. Position 0% means full left in this case. The second applies to the second gradient, and 100% means full right in this case.

This difference is also applied to vertical position, but since the gradient has a size of 100%, it doesn't have any effect

Comment: That's great! Official website explained the background-position property sets the starting position of a background image.but I don't know when there have multiple background images，it set multiple start point; thank you !